# Question about groups and subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

$G$ is finite group and $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$.
How I prove that:
$$K\subset H \Rightarrow [G:H]\cdot [H:K]=[G:K]$$

Id like to get hints for the proof.
Thank you!

Comment: I try to find a direction but I didn't success... I thought about Lagrange Theorem.

Comment: I don't have any idea...:-(

Comment: Think of cosets of $H$ over $G$ and of $K$ over $H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group and $K \subset H \subset G$ a subgroup of $G$. Then by Lagrange we have $|G| = [G:H] \cdot |H|$. So $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$. Now do the same for $[H:K]$ and $[G:K]$, this will give $[H:K] = |H|/|K|$ and $[G:K] = |G|/|K|$. We need $K \subset H$, otherwise we can't talk about the index $[H:K]$. So now we will get:
$$
K \subset H \Rightarrow[G:H] \cdot [H:K] = \frac{|G|}{|H|} \frac{|H|}{|K|} = \frac{|G|}{|K|} = [G:K].
$$

Comment: Can I assume that $K$ is subgroup of $H$?

Comment: Yes otherwise $[H:K]$ makes no sense.

Comment: @YoavFridman Instead of assuming that $K$ is a subgroup of $H$, you could prove it, using the given facts that $K\subseteq H$ and that both of them are subgroups of $G$.